# How to assign cluster, namespace and pod name in kubernetes yaml file's environment variable

Tags: kubernetes, appdynamics, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-namespace

I have a requirement to pass  cluster, namespace and pod name to AppDynamics agent from my container deployed in Kubernetes cluster.

I tried something as below, but that does not work.

```
containers:
      - env:
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=$HOST-$spec.nodeName-spec.PodName
```

and

```
- name: appdynamics.agent.nodeName
  value= $HOST-$spec.nodeName-spec.PodName
```

Could anyone please help me here how to collect the detail and pass to AppD.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

You can get `POD_NAME` and `POD_NAMESPACE` passing them as environment variables via `fieldRef`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-env
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: my-test-image:latest
      env:
        - name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
        - name: REFERENCE_EXAMPLE
          value: "/$(MY_NODE_NAME)/$(MY_POD_NAMESPACE)/$(MY_POD_NAME)/data.log"
  restartPolicy: Never
```

**EDIT**: *Added example env `REFERENCE_EXAMPLE` to show how to reference variables. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582349/kubernetes-how-to-refer-to-one-environment-variable-from-another) answer for pointing out the `$()` interpolation.*

You can reference `supports metadata.name, metadata.namespace, metadata.labels, metadata.annotations, spec.nodeName, spec.serviceAccountName, status.hostIP, status.podIP` as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.12/#envvarsource-v1-core).

However, `CLUSTERNAME` is not a standard property available. According to this [PR #22043](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/22043), the `CLUSTERNAME` should be injected to the `.metadata` field if using GCE.

Otherwise, you'll have to specific the `CLUSTERNAME` manually in the `.metadata` field  and then use `fieldRef` to inject it as an environment variable.

Comment: According to the docs here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.12/#envvarsource-v1-core only a few fields in the spec are supported. Got `field label not supported: status.restartPolicy`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that did not help.                                                                                  Can I use something like this?     - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xmx512m -Xms256m -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=$(metadata.name)

Comment: @SunilChauraha You need to reference the environment variable that Kuberenetes created, not the field in the manifest. So, your first `env` should be  `- name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName` and the second would be `-name: JAVA_OPTS value: -Xmx512m -Xms256m -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=$(MY_NODE_NAME)`

Comment: Thanks @PraveenSripati for confirming that.

Comment: @SunilChauraha I'll edit the answer. Please mark the question as answered. Thanks.

Comment: only name and namespace exist in metadata.
CLUSTER_NAME is only for gce

Answer (score 2):

Below format helped me, suggested by ewok2030 and Praveen.
Only one thing to make sure that the variable should be declared before they are used as JAVA_OPTS.

containers:

```
   - env:

    - name: APPD_NODE_NAME
       valueFrom: 
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
    - name: APPD_POD_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    - name: APP_POD_NAME
      valueFrom: 
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    - name: JAVA_OPTS
      value: -Xmx712m -Xms556m -Dpdp.logging.level=WARN -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=$(APPD_NODE_NAME)-$(APPD_POD_NAMESPACE)-$(APP_POD_NAME)
```