# Kubernetes Windows refer environment variable from another

Tags: kubernetes, docker-for-windows, azure-aks

I want to declare for my pod environment variables that are based on other environment variables like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582349/kubernetes-how-to-refer-to-one-environment-variable-from-another) but for kubernetes on windows.

So with default kubernetes (on linux) it is possible like that:

```
- name: MY_NAME
  value: "$(POD_NAME)"
```

But this doesn't work if you deploy your pod on kubernetes for windows.

Is there any possibility to use the windows environment variables inside the k8s deployment?

Comment: I'm also interested in a solution to this. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the proper answer to my question, but it solved the intended problem:

```
        - name: CLUSTER_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
```