# Interpolation on K8s deployment

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

How do I pass in a variable inside another string value in k8s deployments.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable references are possible using the `$(ENV_VAR)` format.
So, in this example, it would be:

```
containers:
 - env: 
     - name: DATA_SOURCE_PASS
       valueFrom:
         secretKeyRef:
           name: app-secrets
           key: DB_DOCKER_USER_PASSWORD
     - name: PG_EXPORTER_URL
       value: postgres://postgres:$(DATA_SOURCE_PASS)@localhost:5432/postgres
```

- This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582349/kubernetes-how-to-refer-to-one-environment-variable-from-another), which is where I got this answer from.
- Kubernetes documentation on [variable references](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#envvar-v1-core), also linked from article above.