# HOSTNAME env-var returns empty during Docker pod startup

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, debian

When I SSH onto a **running** Docker container in a Kubernetes cluster and run `os.getenv("HOSTNAME")` from within a python interpreter, I am able to see the name of the **deployment** being used.

But if I try and run `os.getenv("HOSTNAME")` in a script that gets run from the `Dockerfile`, the env-var is `null`.

Is this expected? Is there some workaround here?

**UPDATE**: I tried to get the contents from `/etc/hostname` instead and to my surprise I got `debuerreotype`. After some googling I saw that that is the base Debian image in use and apparently [it passes that name as the hostname](https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype/blob/master/docker-run.sh#L50)

- Opened an [Issue](https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype/issues/160) with them in the meantime
- (I still don't understand why I get the correct value when I SSH into the container though)

Comment: It's a question of the shell and OS the container is using. Some shells use $HOST (tcsh) others (bash) use $HOSTNAME.

Comment: The hostname doesn’t matter much for a K8S POD, so, it’s not clear to me how you intend to use the value. If you want to know the POD ID, then you can use the Downward API. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49582349/839733).

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I want to display in the screen which pod is serving that request, for debugging purposes (it's a web application)

Comment: @Martlark just tested it -- didn't work unfortunately. Still `null`

Comment: add `export HOSTNAME=$(hostname)` to your entrypoint script

Comment: i don't have access to the caller script =/

Comment: @Felipe PODs come and go, so, a hostname printed in the logs means absolutely nothing for debugging because that host may no longer be around when the debugging is required. Not to mention that developers usually don't have access to the hostname anyway, so seeing that host abc served a particular user request isn't exactly mind-blowing useful.

Comment: Does [How can I use Python to get the system hostname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271740/how-can-i-use-python-to-get-the-system-hostname) answer your question?  If you do actually need the hostname for whatever reason, `socket.hostname()` is probably the right way to get it.

Comment: @DavidMaze `socket.hostname()` returns a default value (`buildkitsandbox`) when I call it during container startup. And it returns the pod ID when I call with from within a running Container. The problem remains -- different results depending on whether I call it during container startup _or_ from a a running container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was running scripts in the `RUN` step of the `Dockerfile`.

This means that this code runs at **image build time**, so whatever Environment variables I was able to retrieve were those of the build-time environment.

I was able to correctly retrieve the env-vars when I did it inside the code that gets run at **container run time**, i.e. in the `ENTRYPOINT` command.

Comment: I think we've all been there!